# Modify HTML and PHP with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, include, preg-replace, eval

**I have this HTML / PHP content (as a string):**

```
<html>
    <?php my_class->my_function('test.php', 'value1', 'value2');
    <?php my_class->my_function('test2.php', 3);
</html>
```

What my_class->my_function does is including content depending on the values sent.

**It could look something like this**

```
function my_function($file, $value1, $value2)
{
    include $file . $value1 . $value2;
}
```

The result of my_function should be outputted, instead of the function call.

**The result should be**

```
<html>
    <?php
        /* Content from file test.php */
        echo 'This file is test.php, with value1 and value2';
    ?>
    <?php
        /* Content from file test2.php */
        echo 'This file is test2.php, with value 3';
    ?>
</html>
```

I guess I need some kind of preg_replace in combination with eval, include or get_file_contents.

Comment: This sounds like you have a problem, you have decided to solve this problem by the above method. What ever the problem is, there is a better way. Explain the problem, not your proposed solution that doesn't work.

Comment: Upvoted jakenoble because I got confused in what you're trying to do as well.

Comment: This is even more confusing than your [previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723938/split-and-replace-things-with-php-and-preg-replace-instead-of-explode). Please explain why you are not just executing the first script? It's a template thingy or not?

Comment: Any solution that includes the `eval()` function is likely to be a bad idea. There is almost always a better solution.

Comment: I have a system that uses different files and folders. In my "light" free version I only want to give away the generated file, not my whole system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncomplete answer. This is what I got at first when using explode. It works BUT when adding multiple values to the function it creates bugs. One or two values it can handle. Not more and it's too complex for me to handle.

```
function include_layout2($part, $file = '/index.php')
{

    $url = get_layout2($part, $file);
    if(file_exists($url))
    {
        return get_include_contents( $url );
    }
}


function get_layout2($part, $file = '/index.php')
{
    $layout_theme = 'default';
    $addmod_layout = get_option('addmod_layout');
    $layout = $addmod_layout['styles'][$layout_theme][$part]['layout'];
    $layout = (!empty($layout)) ? $layout : 'default';
    $url = TEMPLATEPATH . '/styles/' . $part . '/' . $layout . $file;
    if(file_exists($url))
    {
        return $url;
    }
}

function generate_content($layout = 'index')
{   
    $content = include_layout2($layout);
    $content_a = explode("<?php addmod_include('", $content);

    $save_for_later = $content;
    $counter = 0;
    while(count($content_a) > 1)
    {
        $content_a = explode("<?php addmod_include('", $save_for_later);
        $output = '';
        $save_for_later = '';
        for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($content_a); $i++)
        {
            $content_b = explode("'); ?>", $content_a[$i], 2);
            if(isset($content_b[0]) && !empty($content_b[0]))
            {
                $include_test = include_layout2($content_b[0]);
                if(isset($include_test))
                {
                    $content_b[0] = include_layout2($content_b[0]);
                }
                else
                {
                    $new_layout = explode("addmod_include('", $content_b[0]);
                    $new_file = explode("addmod_include(', '", $content_b[0]);

                    if(isset($new_layout[0]) && isset($new_file[1]))
                    {
                        $content_b[0] = include_layout2($new_layout[0], $new_file[1]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $content_b[0] .=  "'); ?>";
                    }
                }
            }
            $content = implode($content_b);
            $output .= $content;
            $save_for_later .= $content;
        }

        $counter++;
    }
    return $output;
}
echo generate_content();
```

Don't try to run the code because it's a little dependent of some other stuff.

I don't know if that makes it more clear what I need to do?

Comment: Then all you need is `eval ('?>' . generate_content());` instead of `echo generate_content();`, right?

Comment: No, it works without eval because I use get_file_contents and the content is PHP. The problem however is the parsing stuff. Explode makes me confused.