# Preg_replace and preg_match to get and replace HTML / PHP content

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace, preg-match

I need to extract some HTML / PHP content and put it into an array.

**Here is what I have**

The code below is within a string called $string for example.

```
<html>
<?php myclass->my_function('First', 'Last'); ?>
<p>Some other content</p>
<?php myclass->my_function(1, 2, 3); ?>
</html>
```

I want to find all the values from the functions and sum them into an array with preg_match. Only myclass->my_function function values should be found.

**The array should look like this**

```
$array = array(
   1 => array('First', 'Last'),
   2 => array(1,2,3),
);
```

Then I want preg_replace to replace all the rows with [explode_id] and the result should be:

```
<html>
[explode_1]
<p>Some other content</p>
[explode_2]
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: ehhh, where does this string with code come from? why not just have the myclass->myfunction() method print it out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify HTML and PHP with preg_replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724564/modify-html-and-php-with-preg-replace)

Comment: Please don't re-post questions if you don't get any answers that you like.  Instead, edit the question to add more information or clarify what you're looking for...  Voting to close...

Comment: Are you trying to build an array?

Comment: Also related: [Split and replace things with PHP and preg_replace instead of explode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723938/split-and-replace-things-with-php-and-preg-replace-instead-of-explode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = '<html>
<?php myclass->my_function(\'styles\', \'home.css\'); ?>
<p>Some other content</p>
<?php myclass->my_function(1, 2, 3); ?>
</html>';

function jens($matches)
{ 
    $path = '';
    $parts = explode(',', $matches[1]);
    foreach($parts as $match)
        $path .= '/' . str_replace('\'', '', trim($match));

    return $path;
}

$replaced = preg_replace_callback('/<\?php myclass->my_function\((.*?)\); \?>/', 'jens', $str);

echo $replaced;
```

Should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
$match_array = preg_match('/<\?php myclass->my_function\((.+?)\); \?>/', $input_string, $matches);
$output_arrays = array();
$output_arrays[] = eval('array('.$matches[0][1].')';
$output_arrays[] = eval('array('.$matches[1][1].')';

echo '<html>';
echo implode(' ', $output_arrays[0]);
echo '<p>Some other content</p>';
echo implode(' ', $output_arrays[1]);
echo '</html>';
```

Comment: just guessing here. your question doesn't make a lot of sense.